# F# Dsl for simple expression?

Tags: f#

I want to write a generic program to load data from text files or database to a table.

The transformation between the source and destination shouldn't be hard-coded. They may have the format of

```
ColA = Col1 + Col1 * 1.5
ColB = convert Col3 to date
```

These rules may need to be converted to SQL or C# code. Does F# already have some library to do these? Is F# the good language to implement it?

Comment: Way too wide of a question. Try to show more specifics.

Comment: The transformation could be a F# scripting file (.fsx) thus supporting advanced transforms as well as not being hard-coded.

Answer (score 1):

With so few specific details in your question, we can't really give you a good answer. But here are a few F# libraries that you might find useful for what you're trying to do:

- [FSharp.Data](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/) - Whether your incoming data is in SQL, CSV, JSON, or XML, there's a type provider that can parse it for you and let you write type-safe queries against it.
- [FParsec](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/) - Lets you easily write custom parsers, so that you can define your transformations in a custom DSL without too much effort. You mentioned custom DSLs in your title, so that's why I'm recommending FParsec. I've used it myself for exactly that purpose, and it was *great*.

That's about all the help I can give you until I know more details about what you're trying to achieve.